# how to mock an event callback trigger within a jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My component code has:

```
function aa() {
this.component.grid = createItem();
this.component.grid.instance.options.addEventListener('eventAbc',() => { 
  this.bbb ();
})
}

function bbb() {
 console.log("dummy func");
}
```

in component.spec.ts file:

```
let content;
setup() {

content = jasmine.createSpyObj('content', ['createItem']);
content.createItem.and.callFake(() => {
return { 
grid: {
 instance: {
  options: {
      addEventListener: (event, action) => {}
  }}}}}

it('testing method aa', () => { 
spyOn(component.grid.instance.gridOptions, 'addEventListener').andCallThrough();
spyOn(component, 'bbb').and.callThrough();
component.aa();
expect(component.grid.instance.gridOptions.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.bbb).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

I want to understand how to mock triggering the 'abcEvent' so that the test goes inside the real callback of the event listener and bbb method gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I got access to the call back function of the event listener is by:

```
let callBack = addEventListener.calls.allArgs()[0][1]; //this gives access to all the arguments passed to the eventListener method
callBack(); //manually triggered the callback function bbb()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would call `action` in the callback so the `bbb` method gets called.

Something like this:

```
content.createItem.and.callFake(() => {
return { 
grid: {
 instance: {
  options: {
      addEventListener: (event, action) => {
       // !! add the following line, call action method so when you pass
       // bbb there it will be called
       action();
    }
  }}}}}
```